# How Can I access a specify field from field array to calculate Subtotal

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm using form ValueSelector and I'm working with calculated field array. When I use this syntax I've got a syntax issue, but not error on execution's time.

This is the formula for calculate subtotal:

```
   const calculatedSubtotal = 
     (`detail[${this.props.index}].quantity`,`detail[${this.props.index}].product.price`) = 
      `detail[${this.props.index}].quantity` * `detail[${this.props.index}].product.price`
```

And this is the formula to calculate total:

```
   const calculatedTotal = (`detail[${this.props.index}].subtotal`) = 0 + 
         `detail[${this.props.index}].subtotal`
```

When I'm executing those lines, I've got syntax issues.

Detail is the fieldArray's name.

How Can I declare a specify field from field array for calculate?.

What is wrong?

this is my renderDetail Component:

```
      renderDetail = ({fields, meta: { error,submitFailed}}) => (
                 <dl>
                  <dt>
                   <button type="button" className= 'btn btn-primary' 
            onClick={() => fields.push()}>Add Detail</button>
                   {submitFailed && error && <span>{error}</span>}
                  </dt>
                  { fields.map((item, index) =>

                    <dd key={index}>
                     <br></br>
                       <button className= 'btn btn-light mr-2'
                         type="button"
                         title="Remove detail"
                         onClick={() => { fields.remove(index)
                            if(fields.length == 0 || fields.length === 
             undefined){

                         }
                          try{
                           for(let x in fields){
                            fields.remove(index) 
                            let d = fields.selectedIndex;
                             if(fields.remove(index) && d >= 1 && d< 
           fields.length ){
                            fields.removeAll(index);
                            }
                          }
                         }catch{console.info("deletes Index")}

                }}> Delete </button>

                    <h4>Item #{index + 1}</h4>

              <Field 
                 id={`${item}._id`}
                 name={`${item}.quantity`}
                 component= {NumberPicker}
                  placeholder= '...quantity'
                  label = "Quantity" 
                 />
                <br></br>
             <h3><b>Product</b></h3>
                  <Field 
                   id={`${item}._id`}
                   name={`${item}.product.code`}
                   type="number"
                   component= {RenderFieldNumber}
                   placeholder='...Product's code'
                   label = "product's code" 
                  />
                 <Field 
                   id={`${item}._id`}
                   name={`${item}.product.name`}
                   type="text"
                   component= {RenderField}
                   placeholder='...Product's name'
                   label = "product's name" 
                   />
                <Field 
                  id={`${item}._id`}
                  name={`${item}.product.price`}
                  component= {NumberPickerFloat}
                  placeholder= '...Price'
                  label = "Product's price" 
                />
                <br></br>
               <h3><b>Subtotal</b></h3>
                  <Field 
                    id={`${item}._id`}
                    name={`${item}.subtotal`}
                    component= {SubtotalWidget}
                    placeholder= '...subtotal'
                    label = "Subtotal" 
                  />

                </dd>
                      )
                      }

                       {error && <dt className="error">{error}</dt>}
                       </dl> 
                  );
```

And in render method I'm accesing this way to fieldArray:

```
       <div>Detail:</div>
              <FieldArray
                  name='detail'
                  component={this.renderDetail}
                  label='Detail'
                 />
```

Comment: What are the exact errors that you get? And what are you trying to do in both pieces of code? Are you trying to actually calculate the total or are you trying to build a string that shows the formula used for the calculation?

Comment: exact error: I see those code lines with red mark. It must be a syntax error. I'm trying to calculate subtotal and total, respectively. Accesing to specifies fields from field array by index.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? There are a lot of problems with your syntax, but we need to know what you want in order to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've been mistaken. It's react syntax.

Comment: It's not valid React syntax either which is why your getting the errors. When you answer my question, I will be glad to help.

Comment: I want to access specific array fields through specify index (this.props.index) to calculate the subtotal on the one hand and the total on the other, because then I will pass them to the selector

Comment: And to clarify, there is no such thing as "React syntax". React uses two languages: JavaScript and JSX. What you have here appears to be using what are called string template literals, but not correctly.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `calculatedSubtotal` should be a number, not a string. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207705/discussion-between-francisco-arias-and-code-apprentice).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make arrow functions to calculate the values?

```
const calculatedSubtotal = () => detail[this.props.index].quantity * detail[this.props.index].product.price


const calculatedTotal = () => 0 + detail[this.props.index].subtotal
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing way you said me, but I've got same syntax issue.